# Get Weeks In Month Through Javascript

Tags: javascript, calendar

In Javascript, how do I get the number of weeks in a month? I can't seem to find code for this anywhere.

I need this to be able to know how many rows I need for a given month.

To be more specific, I would like the number of weeks that have at least one day in the week (a week being defined as starting on Sunday and ending on Saturday).

So, for something like this, I would want to know it has 5 weeks:

```
S  M  T  W  R  F  S

         1  2  3  4

5  6  7  8  9  10 11

12 13 14 15 16 17 18

19 20 21 22 23 24 25

26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Your question is missing a few parameters. Pleas be more specific. You want the number of complete weeks in an arbitrary month, or you want a   real number of weeks e.g. 4.3, or you want the number of weeks that have at least one day in the month? follow me?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Weeks start on Sunday**

This ought to work even when February doesn't start on Sunday.

```
function weekCount(year, month_number) {

    // month_number is in the range 1..12

    var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number-1, 1);
    var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number, 0);

    var used = firstOfMonth.getDay() + lastOfMonth.getDate();

    return Math.ceil( used / 7);
}
```

**Weeks start on Monday**

```
function weekCount(year, month_number) {

    // month_number is in the range 1..12

    var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number-1, 1);
    var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number, 0);

    var used = firstOfMonth.getDay() + 6 + lastOfMonth.getDate();

    return Math.ceil( used / 7);
}
```

**Weeks start another day**

```
function weekCount(year, month_number, startDayOfWeek) {
  // month_number is in the range 1..12

  // Get the first day of week week day (0: Sunday, 1: Monday, ...)
  var firstDayOfWeek = startDayOfWeek || 0;

  var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number-1, 1);
  var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number, 0);
  var numberOfDaysInMonth = lastOfMonth.getDate();
  var firstWeekDay = (firstOfMonth.getDay() - firstDayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

  var used = firstWeekDay + numberOfDaysInMonth;

  return Math.ceil( used / 7);
}
```

Comment: Used this code for a jQuery calendar plugin. Thanks for sharing! You can check it out here: https://github.com/joelalejandro/jquery-ja/wiki/ja.Calendar

Comment: This is great. Any chance you could explain **why** this works though?

Comment: @Titmael I have updated the solution to make it works with weeks starting any day.

Comment: Still not working when starting with Monday. Just check Jan 2018. It should return 5 weeks, but it returns 6.

Comment: Indeed. Dec 2017 returns 6 weeks, when there are only 5.

Comment: `Weeks start on Monday` function is broken. It only returns `6` for most months. The other ones seem to work fine.

Comment: It should be `-1` not `+6` for `Weeks start on Monday`.

Comment: `+6` only needed if `getDay()` returned 0.

Comment: Monday change: var used = firstOfMonth.getDay() + (firstOfMonth.getDay()===0?6:-1) + lastOfMonth.getDate();

Answer (score 10):

**None of the solutions proposed here don't works correctly, so I wrote my own variant and it works for any cases.**

Simple and working solution:

```
/**
 * Returns count of weeks for year and month
 *
 * @param {Number} year - full year (2016)
 * @param {Number} month_number - month_number is in the range 1..12
 * @returns {number}
 */
var weeksCount = function(year, month_number) {
    var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number - 1, 1);
    var day = firstOfMonth.getDay() || 6;
    day = day === 1 ? 0 : day;
    if (day) { day-- }
    var diff = 7 - day;
    var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number, 0);
    var lastDate = lastOfMonth.getDate();
    if (lastOfMonth.getDay() === 1) {
        diff--;
    }
    var result = Math.ceil((lastDate - diff) / 7);
    return result + 1;
};
```

[you can try it here](https://jsfiddle.net/vf3o2jdm/)

Comment: this is returning wrong result for weeksCount(2018,9)

Comment: for me it returns 5, you means you tried for Sep'2018

Comment: @MasterYoda 
@Prabha
correct result is `5` for Sep'2018
weeksCount(2018,9) 

https://url.upwork.com/_01_GXp87_p0P1s4yQShlUZ9PcxhqsECFVk

Comment: but it `5` if you local week starts from Monday
this function not supported `First day of week` feature

Comment: "None of the solutions proposed here don't works correctly, so I wrote my own variant and it works for any cases." now with every new answer you need to update yours to defend this statement perhaps.

Answer (score 6):

This is very simple two line code. and i have tested 100%.

```
Date.prototype.getWeekOfMonth = function () {
    var firstDay = new Date(this.setDate(1)).getDay();
    var totalDays = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
    return Math.ceil((firstDay + totalDays) / 7);
}
```

How to use

```
var totalWeeks = new Date().getWeekOfMonth();
console.log('Total Weeks in the Month are : + totalWeeks );
```

Comment: I was looking for dart code, found it here lol, thanks you saved my day

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to calculate it.

You can do something like

```
var firstDay = new Date(2010, 0, 1).getDay(); // get the weekday january starts on
var numWeeks = 5 + (firstDay >= 5 ? 1 : 0); // if the months starts on friday, then it will end on sunday
```

Now we just need to genericize it.

```
var dayThreshold = [ 5, 1, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5 ];
function GetNumWeeks(month, year)
{
    var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
    var baseWeeks = (month == 1 ? 4 : 5); // only February can fit in 4 weeks
    // TODO: account for leap years
    return baseWeeks + (firstDay >= dayThreshold[month] ? 1 : 0); // add an extra week if the month starts beyond the threshold day.
}
```

**Note:** When calling, remember that months are zero indexed in javascript (i.e. January == 0).

Answer (score 3):

```
function weeksinMonth(m, y){
 y= y || new Date().getFullYear();
 var d= new Date(y, m, 0);
 return Math.floor((d.getDate()- 1)/7)+ 1;     
}
alert(weeksinMonth(3))
```

// the month range for this method is 1 (january)-12(december)

Comment: now in a normal scenerio  , week ends at saturday . Lets say the month is september and year is 2018 . Then weeks should come out to be 6 . See you calender

Comment: The answer above just counts the number of "7 days" groups. So all 28 days long Februaries will be return "4" weeks, whatever the starting day is.

Answer (score 3):

The most easy to understand way is

```
<div id="demo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function numberOfDays(year, month)
 {
   var d = new Date(year, month, 0);
   return d.getDate();
 }


 function getMonthWeeks(year, month_number)
 {
   var $num_of_days       = numberOfDays(year, month_number)
    ,  $num_of_weeks      = 0
    ,  $start_day_of_week = 0; 

   for(i=1; i<=$num_of_days; i++)
   {
      var $day_of_week = new Date(year, month_number, i).getDay();
      if($day_of_week==$start_day_of_week)
      {
        $num_of_weeks++;
      }   
   }

    return $num_of_weeks;
 }

   var d = new Date()
      , m = d.getMonth()
      , y = d.getFullYear();

   document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = getMonthWeeks(y, m);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

using moment js

```
function getWeeksInMonth(year, month){

        var monthStart     = moment().year(year).month(month).date(1);
        var monthEnd       = moment().year(year).month(month).endOf('month');
        var numDaysInMonth = moment().year(year).month(month).endOf('month').date();

        //calculate weeks in given month
        var weeks      = Math.ceil((numDaysInMonth + monthStart.day()) / 7);
        var weekRange  = [];
        var weekStart = moment().year(year).month(month).date(1);
        var i=0;

        while(i<weeks){
            var weekEnd   = moment(weekStart);


            if(weekEnd.endOf('week').date() <= numDaysInMonth && weekEnd.month() == month) {
                weekEnd = weekEnd.endOf('week').format('LL');
            }else{
                weekEnd = moment(monthEnd);
                weekEnd = weekEnd.format('LL')
            }

            weekRange.push({
                'weekStart': weekStart.format('LL'),
                'weekEnd': weekEnd
            });


            weekStart = weekStart.weekday(7);
            i++;
        }

        return weekRange;
    } console.log(getWeeksInMonth(2016, 7))
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 variant, using consistent zero-based months index. Tested for years from 2015 to 2025.

```
/**
 * Returns number of weeks
 *
 * @param {Number} year - full year (2018)
 * @param {Number} month - zero-based month index (0-11)
 * @param {Boolean} fromMonday - false if weeks start from Sunday, true - from Monday.
 * @returns {number}
 */
const weeksInMonth = (year, month, fromMonday = false) => {
    const first = new Date(year, month, 1);
    const last  = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
    let dayOfWeek = first.getDay();
    if (fromMonday && dayOfWeek === 0) dayOfWeek = 7;
    let days = dayOfWeek + last.getDate();
    if (fromMonday) days -= 1;
    return Math.ceil(days / 7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [my time.js library](http://github.com/augustl/time.js). Here's the weeksInMonth function:

```
// http://github.com/augustl/time.js/blob/623e44e7a64fdaa3c908debdefaac1618a1ccde4/time.js#L67

weeksInMonth: function(){
  var millisecondsInThisMonth = this.clone().endOfMonth().epoch() - this.clone().firstDayInCalendarMonth().epoch();
  return Math.ceil(millisecondsInThisMonth / MILLISECONDS_IN_WEEK);
},
```

It might be a bit obscure since the meat of the functionality is in endOfMonth and firstDayInCalendarMonth, but you should at least be able to get some idea of how it works.

Comment: How would you call the function in another script? (I'm not too good with Javascript just yet)

Comment: Include the js file on your page, and do something like `new Time(2008, 11).weeksInMonth()`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't this give the same result for a February with 28 days that starts on a Sunday, and a standard February that starts on any other day of the week? They are both exactly 4 week lengths, but the first will display in 4 rows, the second will take 5.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me,

```
function(d){
    var firstDay = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 1).getDay();
    return Math.ceil((d.getDate() + (firstDay - 1))/7);
}
```

"d" should be the date.

Answer (score 1):

A little rudimentary, yet should cater for original post :

```
/**
 * @param {date} 2020-01-30
 * @return {int} count
 */
this.numberOfCalendarWeekLines = date => {
    
    // get total
    let lastDayOfMonth = new Date( new Date( date ).getFullYear(), new Date( date ).getMonth() + 1, 0 );
    
    let manyDaysInMonth = lastDayOfMonth.getDate();
    
    // iterate over month - from 1st
    // count calendar week lines by occurrence
    // of a Saturday ( s m t w t f s )
    let countCalendarWeekLines = 0;
    
    for ( let i = 1; i <= manyDaysInMonth; i++ ) {
        
        if ( new Date( new Date( date ).setDate( i ) ).getDay() === 6 ) countCalendarWeekLines++;
        
    }
    
    // days after last occurrence of Saturday 
    // leaked onto new line?
    if ( lastDayOfMonth.getDay() < 6 ) countCalendarWeekLines++;
    
    return countCalendarWeekLines;
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ed Poor for his solution, this is the same as Date prototype.

```
Date.prototype.countWeeksOfMonth = function() {
  var year         = this.getFullYear();
  var month_number = this.getMonth();
  var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number-1, 1);
  var lastOfMonth  = new Date(year, month_number, 0);
  var used         = firstOfMonth.getDay() + lastOfMonth.getDate();
  return Math.ceil( used / 7);
}
```

So you can use it like

```
var weeksInCurrentMonth = new Date().countWeeksOfMonth();
var weeksInDecember2012 = new Date(2012,12,1).countWeeksOfMonth(); // 6
```

Comment: That looks like the object-oriented way to define the function. Great for those of us with advanced programming skills.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to specify the startWeekDay, for instance January 2017 starts a Sunday so it is 5 weeks if week starts a Sunday and 6 if the week starts a Monday.

Comment: Natim, I think your edit to my OP is the same as my Jan 2018 re-post. (I just don't know how to use the || operator, so I did a modulus trick.)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code give you the exact number of weeks in a given month:

```
Date.prototype.getMonthWeek = function(monthAdjustement)
{       
    var firstDay = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 1).getDay();
    var returnMessage = (Math.ceil(this.getDate()/7) + Math.floor(((7-firstDay)/7)));
    return returnMessage;
}
```

The `monthAdjustement` variable adds or substract the month that you are currently in

I use it in a calendar project in JS and the equivalent in Objective-C and it works well

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWeeksInMonth(month_number, year) {
  console.log("year - "+year+" month - "+month_number+1);

  var day = 0;
  var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number, 1);
  var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, parseInt(month_number)+1, 0);

  if (firstOfMonth.getDay() == 0) {
    day = 2;
    firstOfMonth = firstOfMonth.setDate(day);
    firstOfMonth = new Date(firstOfMonth);
  } else if (firstOfMonth.getDay() != 1) {
    day = 9-(firstOfMonth.getDay());
    firstOfMonth = firstOfMonth.setDate(day);
    firstOfMonth = new Date(firstOfMonth);
  }

  var days = (lastOfMonth.getDate() - firstOfMonth.getDate())+1
  return Math.ceil( days / 7);              
}
```

It worked for me. Please try

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
    function weekCount(year, month_number, day_start) {

        // month_number is in the range 1..12
        // day_start is in the range 0..6 (where Sun=0, Mon=1, ... Sat=6)

        var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number-1, 1);
        var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number, 0);

        var dayOffset = (firstOfMonth.getDay() - day_start + 7) % 7;
        var used = dayOffset + lastOfMonth.getDate();

        return Math.ceil( used / 7);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming late, I have seen codes upon codes trying to get the number of weeks a particular month falls on, but many have not been really precise but most have been really informative and reusable, I'm not an expert programmer but I can really think and thanks to some codes by some people I was able to arrive at a conclusion.

```
function convertDate(date) {//i lost the guy who owns this code lol
var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
var dd  = date.getDate().toString();

var mmChars = mm.split('');
var ddChars = dd.split('');

return yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1]?mm:"0"+mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1]?dd:"0"+ddChars[0]);
}

//this line of code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028614/2540911
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

var myDate = new Date('2019-03-2');  
//var myDate = new Date(); //or todays date

var c = convertDate(myDate).split("-"); 
let yr = c[0], mth = c[1], dy = c[2];

weekCount(yr, mth, dy)

//Ahh yes, this line of code is from Natim Up there, incredible work, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485172/2540911
function weekCount(year, month_number, startDayOfWeek) {
// month_number is in the range 1..12
  console.log(weekNumber);

// Get the first day of week week day (0: Sunday, 1: Monday, ...)
var firstDayOfWeek = startDayOfWeek || 0;

var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number-1, 1);
var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number, 0);
var numberOfDaysInMonth = lastOfMonth.getDate();
var first = firstOfMonth.getDate();

//initialize first week
let weekNumber = 1;
while(first-1 < numberOfDaysInMonth){    
// add a day
firstOfMonth = firstOfMonth.setDate(firstOfMonth.getDate() + 1);//this line of code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989458/2540911
if(days[firstOfMonth.getDay()] === "Sunday"){//get new week every new sunday according the local date format
  //get newWeek
  weekNumber++;          
}

  if(weekNumber === 3 && days[firstOfMonth.getDay()] === "Friday")
    alert(firstOfMonth);

  first++
 }
}
```

I needed this code to generate a schedule or event scheduler for a church on every 3rd friday of a new month, so you can modify this to suit your or just pick your specific date, not "friday and specify the week of the month and Voila!! here you go

Comment: I realised it doesnt fully perfom the function of the event scheduler on days after the specified date i.e friday for the month of july 2019, i was able to modify my code to correctly, eventually, `therefore ignore the " if(weekNumber === 3 && days[firstOfMonth.getDay()] === "Friday")"

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here really worked for me. Here is my crack at it.

```
// Example
// weeksOfMonth(2019, 9) // October
// Result: 5
weeksOfMonth (year, monthIndex) {
  const d = new Date(year, monthIndex+ 1, 0)
  const adjustedDate = d.getDate() + d.getDay()
  return Math.ceil(adjustedDate / 7)
}
```

Comment: weeksOfMonth(2020, 7), for august 2020 it should be 6, but it returned 5.

Answer (score 0):

Every solutions helped but nothing was working for me so I did my own with moment library :

```
const getWeeksInAMonth = (currentDate: string) => {
    const startOfMonth = moment(currentDate).startOf("month")
    const endOfMonth = moment(currentDate).endOf("month")
    return moment(endOfMonth).week() - moment(startOfMonth).week() + 1
}
```

Comment: Perhaps add some actual dates where this is called and show the results and make this an even better answer.  You can even create a snippet and add moment from a cdn like this one `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>`

Comment: This looks good, but not working correctly in December

Answer (score 0):

Wrote something extremely simple and direct and works for his usecase which was also my usecase

```
function countWeeksInMonth(year, month_number) {
  // month_number is in the range 1..12
  const date = new Date(year, month_number);
  const startDay = new Date(year, month_number, 1).getDay();
  let totalDays = new Date(year, month_number + 1, 0).getDate();
  let weeks = 0;

  console.log("total-days initial", { totalDays });

  // Step 1: Remove first week
  totalDays -= 7 - startDay;
  weeks += 1;
  console.log("Step 1:", { totalDays, weeks });

  // Step 2: Count the full weeks
  weeks += Math.floor(totalDays / 7);
  console.log("Step 2:", { weeks });

  // Step 3: Check for overflowing weeks
  if (totalDays % 7 > 0) weeks += 1;
  console.log("Step 3:", { weeks });

  return weeks;
}
```