# Extract day and week number of a specific month given a specific date or time stamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Preferred in jQuery, if possible, otherwise any Javascript will work.

I'd like to get the day and week number of month given a specific date or timestamp.

For example

2010-10-26 would return Tuesday and 4 as the week number

2010-11-11 would return Thursday and 2 as the week number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into the [Javascript date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date).

To get the day of the week, you need to do something like the following:

```
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

var myDate = new Date('2010-10-26');

var dayOfWeek = days[myDate.getDay()]; // dayOfWeek == 'Tuesday'
```

This is because `getDay()` returns a number 0-6 rather than a string.  This is useful e.g. for internationalisation.

Your other requirement (week of month) would need custom coding -- it can't be done using the native JS date object.