# GetWeek of Month, Week starts from Monday

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how to get the weekNumber in a month for a given date. week should start from monday.

I tried this

```
var firstDay = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 1).getDay();
return Math.ceil((this.getDate() + firstDay)/7);
```

but could not get the exact week number when the month does not starts with monday.

Thanks all

Comment: Look here maybe it's helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483719/get-weeks-in-month-through-javascript

Comment: Sorry sybren, Im actually looking for the week number in a month for the given date. (i.e) 24th May,2015 is 3rd week in May. Week starting for monday

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280323/get-week-of-the-month

Comment: check this out http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Day_of_the_Week

Comment: Not actually. Im looking for the week count with monday as start day