# how to get weeks in particular month with dates in java script

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
const date = new Date();
const startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);  
const endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

 const getDateArray = function(start, end) {
 const arr = [];
 const dt = new Date(start);
  while (dt <= end) {
     arr.push(new Date(dt));
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
     }
      return arr;
     }
  const dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);
```

in this above code I got the current month date list `dateArr`, Now I need to group the days by a week, from the week list I need to filter only week start date and weekend date that must be in list formate I tried with the above code but I cant proceed to next.

Comment: what you need specifically. Please mention that. How do you want weeks data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483719/get-weeks-in-month-through-javascript refer this like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Weeks In Month Through Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483719/get-weeks-in-month-through-javascript)

Comment: @stack26  i had rewrite the code can u check and tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log("All Weeks : ", getWeeksInaMonth())
console.log("Current Week : ", getCurrentWeek())
console.log("Current and previous weeks : ",getCurrAndPrevWeeks())

function getFormattedDate(dateobj)
{
    var date = dateobj.getDate(), month = dateobj.getMonth()+1, year = dateobj.getFullYear();
    var formattddate = (date<10?"0":"")+date+"/"+(month<10?"0":"")+month+"/"+year;
    return formattddate;
}

function getWeeksInaMonth()
{
    var startdate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1); 
    var enddate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0);
    var weeks = [];
    for(var i=1,n=enddate.getDate();i<n;)
    {
        startdate.setDate(i);
        var arr = [getFormattedDate(startdate)];
        i =i+ 6-startdate.getDay();
        if(i>n) i=i-(i-n);
        startdate.setDate(i);
        arr.push(getFormattedDate(startdate));
        i++;
        weeks.push(arr);
    }
    return weeks
}

function getCurrentWeek()
{
    var today = new Date(), day = today.getDay();
    return [getFormattedDate(new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-day)),
            getFormattedDate(new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+6-day))];
}

function getCurrAndPrevWeeks()
{
    var startdate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1); 
    var enddate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0);
    var today = new Date().getDate();
    var weeks = [];
    for(var i=1,n=enddate.getDate();i<n;)
    {
        startdate.setDate(i);
        var arr = [getFormattedDate(startdate)];
        i =i+ 6-startdate.getDay();
        if(i>n) i=i-(i-n);
        startdate.setDate(i);
        arr.push(getFormattedDate(startdate));
        weeks.push(arr);
        if(today>=i-6 && today<=i) break;
        i++;
    }
    return weeks;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. if it possible to show like this output `{startDate:"01/01/2018", endDate:"06/01/2018" }`

Comment: Modified the array type to object type as required.
Replace the following lines : 
2nd :
`var obj = {};
obj.startDate = getFormattedDate(startdate);`
6th :
`obj.endDate = getFormattedDate(startdate);`
8th :
`weeks.push(obj);`

Comment: You mean "The present week" ?

Comment: is it possible to show prev week start date and end date,  current week start date and end date only in the array. Example `[ "01/01/2018", "07/01/2018"] ,[ "08/01/2018", "14/01/2018"] `

Comment: Updated them. @AaruMugam